# SQL Server - execute JOB in DST not UTC

Tags: sql-server

we have many JOBs that need execute at 10.00AM localtime everyday. But SQL Server time is in UTC, so there is not winter/summer time. So to achieve it, in winter time we need to change time execute to 9:00AM UTC, in Summer need to change to 10.00 UTC manually.

Is it any possibility to set 10:00AM and it will execute at 10:00 winter time and 10:00 summer time?

Comment: Change the time of your SQL Server so that it's clock is GMT/BST and not UTC? Sounds like you shuold be changing the environmental settings on the server itself.

Comment: And the alternative is to schedule your job to to run at 9 and 10, and put in a job step that terminates the job if it's not the correct time.

Comment: "put in a job step that terminates the job if it's not the correct time" - any Ideas how to do that?